# Python 3 - Regex or other way to check for word in variable?

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
for post in socket("news", start=currentTime):
    if post["body"] == 'xyz' and post["author"] == 'admin' and post["url"] == 'latestnews':
        try: 
 print ("Found it!")
(...)
```

It's working, but only if `post["body"]` is *"xyz"*. If `post["body"]` is *"Bla bla bla xyz"* then it's not working. What should I do if I want my script to dispaly *"Found it!"* even if `post["body"]` contains

> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eum ne maiorum volutpat, ei has erat
>   eruditi, autem fierent evertitur at has **xyz** Case simul persius id
>   mei, soleat laoreet assentior ea mel. Meis assum contentiones in cum,
>   est ornatus salutandi id. Sanctus labores ius ne."

Sorry, but I'm new to Python :-/

Comment: You want `in` not `==`.

Comment: @Jan: Morgan knows better than to write a full answer to a common dupe. :)

Comment: Thank you @MorganThrapp :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is change your ordering. You can use the operator 'in' to check if a string contains another string.

```
if 'xyz' in 'oiurwernjfndj xyz iekjerk':
    print True
```

Answer (score -2):

You can probably just use in operator or str.find: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#in https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=index#str.find

Basically, you would do

```
if(xyz in post["body"] ...) { 
// OR 
if(post["body"].find('xyz') != -1 and ... ) {
```

The in operator is probably the fastest way.

The .find will return a number between 0 and string length -1 (to tell you the location of the string. However, if it cannot find the string, it returns a -1. So if it returns -1, then it isn't there, so anything other than -1 means it is.

Comment: No, this is incredibly un-idiomatic. Use `in`.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, all my years not coding python I've gotten so used to doing indexof operations.